# Cross-site Windows and Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET site on a public web server, where users login using forms authentication.

I would like users within certain organisations to be able to login automatically through Windows authentication (bypassing the login page). However, because these clients are on lots of different servers, I can't just build in Windows security to the main site. (I know there are articles on how to mix Windows and Forms security.)

My idea is for each organisation to install a page onto their intranet which redirects to my website and authenticates the user according to their Windows domain and username. Is this possible to achieve securely? How could I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described is almost ***federated identity***.

As well as a page on each site, you will also need a webservice whch will validate a token.

Essentially the flow is:
User comes to your logon page
you redirect them to their company logon page
their company logon page takes their credentials and redirects back to you returning a token

you then call their webservice to validate the token an determine who the user is.

Many public API's use this scheme (facebook being a notable example).

look up oauth and federated identity for more information.